# Reclassify in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, reclassify

I have a raster file (DEM) whose values range from 0 to 1565 meters (elevation). I want to extract a new raster file after classifying the values in four classes like this:

> <= to 150 meters
>   150-600 meters
>   600-900 meters
>  >900 meters

after that I want to make statistical calculations.

How can I do this in QGIS?

I have installed the LecoS plugin and I probably don't have the NumPy, SciPy, Pip libraries installed, because it doesn't work.

- How can I see if I have these libraries?
- How do I install these libraries, if I don't have them?
- Is there an easiest way to extract a classified raster file?

I have Windows 7 Pro (64-bit) and QGIS 2.18.7

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to reclassify a raster in QGIS using GRASS tool `r.reclass`. When you installed QGIS you probably installed GRASS as well. In the processing toolbox of QGIS go to GRASS/raster/r.reclass

[image]

Select the input raster layer, and then you can open a txt file containing reclassification rules. If you want 4 classes the file must contain the following:

```
1   thru    150 =   1
151 thru    600 =   2
601 thru    900 =   3
901 thru    1565    =   4
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with GRASS GIS. I have just started in QGIS. Any other ideas? Perhaps using Raster Calculator?

Comment: Don’t worry, you don´t have to work in GRASS, its functionalities are implemented in QGIS. Open QGIS and press Ctrl+Alt+T to open the Processing toolbox (if it is not open already). Then type ‘r.reclass’ in the search bar to find the tool.

Comment: This seems easy, but, why don't I see any results? Shouldn't I give a name to my new reclassified raster in Reclassified field? Even though I'm doing this, I get no result in return. Nothing appears on my screen and nothing is saved anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of GRASS, I used SAGA (2.3.2) Raster tools and it worked at last! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

QGIS 3.2 has native, simple to use reclassification algorithms available through the processing toolbox.

Comment: sorry, I'm working with a company's computer device. It's not easy for me to download new editions.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using the steps below....
**C**heck min max values in first raster (dem),
**U**se Processing Toolbox > SAGA (2.3.2) > Reclassify values (simple)
*Grid* = dem (my first raster),
*Replace Condition* = [2] Low value <=grid valueLookup table = a fixed table with 4 rows created in Fixed table window,
*Changed Grid* = Save to temporary file,
Check on *Open output file after running algorithm*
**R**un (algorithm)
The *Changed Grid* raster appears on project.

**A**fter that arrange the style through properties and save as dem_reclass.tif
**A**fter that statistical analysis can be made through LecoS plugin (if it is installed)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out.
Go to QGIS Processing Toolbox, then follow the snaps. Hope this will help
[Snap 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSpBA.png)
[Snap [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1U2Y.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1U2Y.png)

Comment: SAGA (2.3.2) Raster tools > Reclassify values (simple) worked for me! Thank you!